# Context-free grammar for DAGs?

Tags: graphs, context-free, formal-grammars, modelling, dag

I'm looking for a "safe" representation of DAGs. With "safe" representation I mean that it can be described by a context-free grammar. Ideally, this grammar would be suitable for a simple LR parser.

The same problem for trees instead of DAGs is already solved: Just use one of the many well-known tree representations such as s-expressions or JSON, which are all context-free with nice, efficient parsers.

But how to approach that for DAGs instead of trees?

- The naive approach is a list of nodes, where each node contains refereces to their parent (head) nodes. Ignoring referential integrity, this would be a regular language. But then I need to check that all references point back to an already-parsed node. How do I ensure this? Is there a clever PDA construction for that?
- Or, do I need a totally different representation of DAGs?
- Or, is any generic representation of DAGs doomed to be context-sensitive? If so, is there a proof for that?

I'm aware that in natural language processing, there do exist parsers which output a "parse DAG" instead of a parse tree. But I do not see how these may help in this particular problem. Maybe these are of no help here, but their existence gives me a feeling that this problem might have a solution.

(I became inspired to this question by the [LANGSEC](http://langsec.org/) movement, here are some [Slides](http://langsec.org/insecurity-theory-28c3.pdf) of them.)

Comment: I don't have a proof right now, but I think that DAGs have no context-free representation. For practical purpose, regular syntax with a static semantics that can be efficiently checked (linear parsing time seems achievable) should be sufficient. It comes down to this: what do you mean resp. want to achieve by "safe"?

Comment: [Context-Free Graph Grammars](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-59126-6_3) by J. Engelfriet (1997) may be of interest.

Comment: Minor typo, fixed.